# HttpGet Web APi in .net Core not reading data from [FromBody] Body

Tags: asp.net-core, response, http-get

I am trying to read data from Body for HttpGet method in .net core solution.
Locally its working fine we didn't faced any issue and get proper output as well. 
Below is the code snippet.

```
    **[HttpGet]
    [Route("XYZ")]
    public IActionResult GetXYZ([FromBody]GetXYZModel model)
    {
       // do something
    }**
```

But once its deployed on Server its not able to read data from body. its giving us an below error response.

```
{
    "data": null,
    "statusCode": "",
    "errorDetails": [
        {
            "key": "Model Validation",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "",
                    "errorDescription": "A non-empty request body is required."
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "successDetails": [] }
```

Comment: HTTP GET requests do not allow a body

Comment: Then how it's run locally